# Problema al realizar un INSERT

Tags: java, sql-server-2012

he estado trabajado en la insercion en un proyecto al momento de hacerlo me lanza la siguiente excepción de SQL

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: El índice 33 está fuera de intervalo.
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.setterGetParam(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:714)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.setValue(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:723)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.setString(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:1048)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.setString(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:142)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.setString(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:142)
>       at com.guatex.servicio.pilrut_historia.datos.CapturaDatos.InsertDataPilrut(CapturaDatos.java:83)
>       at com.guatex.servicio.pilrut_historia.entidades.E_Parseo.parseoXML(E_Parseo.java:313)
>       at com.guatex.servicio.pilrut_historia.Servicio_PilrutHistoria.sincronizacion(Servicio_PilrutHistoria.java:50)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.InstanceResolver$1.invoke(InstanceResolver.java:246)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:146)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandler.invoke(EndpointMethodHandler.java:257)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:95)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:629)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:588)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:573)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:470)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:295)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:515)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:285)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:143)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doGet(WSServletDelegate.java:155)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doPost(WSServletDelegate.java:189)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet.doPost(WSServlet.java:76)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Sería muchísimo más útil que coloques el código que tienes además del error que muestras :D

Answer (score 0):

La traza indica que estás haciendo un `PreparedStatement.setString(33, "Un String")` pero al parecer la consulta no tiene un parámetro en la posición 33.